Out of Memory For List of Strings
I am trying a problem in LeetCode and it seems almost done. This is what I have done so far: Fiddle and problem link - 30. Substring with Concatenation of All Words. Following is the code snippet that I did so far:
static IList < int > FindSubstring(string s, string[] words) {
    var list = new List < IList < string >> ();
    DoPermutation(words, 0, words.Length - 1, list);

    return TrackIndexes(s, list);
  }

  static IList < IList < string >> DoPermutation(string[] str, int start, int end, IList < IList < string >> list) {
    if (start == end) {
      list.Add(new List < string > (str));
    } else {
      for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        Swap(ref str[start], ref str[i]);

        DoPermutation(str, start + 1, end, list);

        Swap(ref str[start], ref str[i]);
      }
    }

    return list;
  }

  static void Swap(ref string a, ref string b) {
    var temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }

  static List < int > TrackIndexes(string pattern, IList < IList < string >> aLst) {
    int count = 0;

    List < string > strings;
    List < int > indexes = new List < int > ();

    foreach(var item in aLst) {
      string str = "";

      strings = new List < string > {
        String.Concat(item)
      };

      foreach(var list in item) {
        str += list;

        if (str.Length == strings[0].Length && pattern.Contains(str)) {
          indexes.AddRange(AllIndexesOf(pattern, str));
          count += 1;
        }
      }
    }

    indexes.Sort();
    return indexes.Distinct().ToList();
  }

public static int[] AllIndexesOf(string str, string substr, bool ignoreCase = false) 
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(substr)) 
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("String or substring is not specified.");
  }

  var indexes = new List<int>();
  int index = 0;

  while ((index = str.IndexOf(substr, index, ignoreCase ? StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase : StringComparison.Ordinal)) != -1) 
  {
    indexes.Add(index++);
  }

  return indexes.ToArray();
}

The issue I have is the following input:
s = "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", 

words = ["dhvf","sind","ffsl","yekr","zwzq","kpeo","cila","tfty","modg","ztjg","ybty","heqg","cpwo","gdcj","lnle","sefg","vimw","bxcb"]

The code I have creates a list of possible permutations in the DoPermutation method and for the above input, it generates a list of strings that gets out of memory error. I am not sure if anything can be altered using the code snippet I have.
For now, my code passes 151 out of 180 test cases. Is there anyway using the existing code snippet to get rid of the memory exception or I have to rethink for the problem?
Objective: The main objective of the code is to create possible permutation for list of strings and match those string in a pattern as substring.

Do you really need to create a fully materialized List<List<string>> of permutations?  Or could you just create an IEnumerable<List<string>> enumerable where only one list is materialized at once?

As I pointed out in my comment on your previous question that you deleted, your current algorithm creates a massive number of permutations: 6,402,373,705,728,000 for only 18 words. Even if you avoid the memory allocation, this would take days to finish execution. You need to find something with lower algorithmic complexity.

Since all strings in the array words are the same length and the maximum length (30) is quite small, we can try every possible equivalence class with the length of one word as the modulus. For each one, we can use a sliding window to keep track of the largest matching substring in O(|s|) (where |s| denotes the length of s).
Overall time complexity: O(|w| * |s|) (where w represents one word). This is also equivalent to O(30 * |s|) as the maximum length of one word is 30 characters.
public IList<int> FindSubstring(string s, string[] words) {
    int wlen = words[0].Length;
    var freq = words.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
    var res = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < wlen; i++) {
        var curr = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int l = i, r = l; r + wlen <= s.Length; r += wlen) {
            var w = s.Substring(r, wlen);
            curr.TryGetValue(w, out var currCnt);
            curr[w] = currCnt + 1;
            for (; curr[w] > freq.GetValueOrDefault(w, 0); l += wlen)
                --curr[s.Substring(l, wlen)];
            if (r - l == (words.Length - 1) * wlen)
                res.Add(l);
        }
    }
    return res;
}


Your problem is that you are materializing a list of all possible permutations of your words.  However, there is no need to do that.  All you need to do is to  enumerate the possible permutations and test each one for some condition.  in C# this can be done by implementing an IEnumerable<string []> method that only materializes one string array at a time.
The following is one such, written against .NET 8 / C# 12:
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    ///<summary>
    ///Enumerate the possible permutations of the incoming array.  
    ///Note that the memory of the returned array is reused for the next permutation
    ///</summary>
    public static IEnumerable<T []> EnumeratePermutations<T>(this T [] array)
    {
        if (array.Length == 0)
        {
            yield return array;
            yield break;
        }
        
        // Mutate a copy rather than the original
        var copy = array.ToArray();
        
        static IEnumerable<T []> EnumeratePermutations(T [] array, int start)
        {
            if (start >= array.Length)
                throw new ArgumentException("start >= array.Length");
            for (int i = start; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Swap(ref array[start], ref array[i]);
                yield return array;
                Swap(ref array[start], ref array[i]);
            }
        }

        var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<T []>>();
        try
        {
            stack.Push(EnumeratePermutations(copy, 0).GetEnumerator());
            while (stack.Count != 0)
            {
                var enumerator = stack.Peek();
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                    stack.Pop().Dispose();
                else if (stack.Count < copy.Length)
                    stack.Push(EnumeratePermutations(enumerator.Current, stack.Count).GetEnumerator());
                else
                    yield return enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (var enumerator in stack)
                enumerator.Dispose();
        }
    }
    
    static void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b) 
    {
        var temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
}

I chose to implement this with an explicit stack rather than with recursion for performance reasons, and to avoid potential stack overflows.
Then you could modify your TrackIndexes() to take an IEnumerable<string []> aLst argument, and proceed as before:
static List<int> TrackIndexes(string pattern, IEnumerable<string []> aLst) {
  // TODO: write and test this yourself
}

That being said, while this will solve your out-of-memory problem, it won't pass 30. Substring with Concatenation of All Words.  Simply generating every permutation then checking to see whether the concatenation is contained in the target string will take O(s.Length * Factorial(words.Length)) which won't be fast enough to pass the test.  You're going to need to vastly cut down the number of permutations you enumerate by doing some quick rejects, or switch to an alternate approach as suggested by Glubus in their answer.

You got me to actually do the puzzle for funzies now.
While your solution might work with some optimizations, I think you should step away from your current idea and rethink the problem.
Try to re-explain the problem to yourself.
Hint: the usage of the word  "permutation" is kind of a bait to get you into generating this list. Try to express the problem without this usage.
Hint with minor spoilers
The way I solved it was using these method names and signatures:
public IList<int> FindSubstring(string s, string[] words)
Dictionary<string, int> ExtractWordOccurances(string candidateSubstring, int chopSize)
bool SubStringMeetsRequirements(Dictionary<string, int> extractedChunks, string[] words)
This solution is still very inefficient and is just my first approach without considering run time and memory usage too much. Probably there is more clever approaches still.

Yea of course, I wouldn't put an answer if the solution was invalid or if I was unsure about it. It's not efficient though like I mentioned.
